# Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Tags: php, oracle

I am new to Oracle database. I have created a table in Oracle.  I can get some value from HTML using PHP using `$_POST[]`, and connection works fine.

Now I want to store current Date from PHP into an Oracle table as Date type.  But I don't know the correct way to bind the Date, and I get this error:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
$year = $_POST["SALYR"];
$month = $_POST["SALMT"];
$empID = $_POST["EMPID"];
$dptCode = $_POST["DPTID"];
$salHD = 'A9';
$description = $_POST["DESCR"];
$amount = $_POST["ALAMT"];
$optID = 111;
$trDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime( date("Y/m/d") ) );  

    $query = "INSERT INTO PAYROLLFILE VALUES (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4, :bind5, :bind6, :bind7, :bind8, to_date(:bind9 ,'Y/m/d'))"; 
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind1", $year);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind2", $month);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind3", $empID);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind4", $dptCode);    
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind5", $salHD);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind6", $description);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind7", $amount);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind8", $optID);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind9", $trDate);  //it is line 46
    $r = oci_execute($stid);  //it is line 47
```

Please tell me where I made a syntax error in the Oracle date conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this Statement

```
$query = "INSERT INTO PAYROLLFILE VALUES (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4, :bind5, :bind6, :bind7, :bind8, to_date(:bind9 ,'Y/m/d'))";
```

with this query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO PAYROLLFILE VALUES (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4, :bind5, :bind6, :bind7, :bind8, to_date(:bind9 ,'YY/mm/dd'))";
```

Comment: thanks it worked can you please tell me what was wrong is that just syntax or any function.thanks

Comment: You are missing the format mask of oracle date format. you are using to_date(:bind9 ,'Y/m/d'))" but it is wrong. Single Y or single m or single d is not supported in oracle.